# Dropdowns are not working using react-draft-wysiwyg in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-draft-wysiwyg

I tried to use `react-draft-wysiwyg` using the [docs](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg)

Some icons are displayed but not working : `block type`, `font`, `font size`,`pickerColor` (the dropdowns are not working). For example, the `font size` is set to 16 by defauft, but I can't change it...

```
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

const TabContent = ({ name, typeProof }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(
  () => EditorState.createEmpty(),);


  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Editor
          editorState={text}
          onEditorStateChange={setText}
          wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
          editorClassName="editorClassName"
          toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
          placeholder="Enter your text here:"
          style={{
           //some styles
          }}
          toolbar={{
            options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'colorPicker', 'embedded', 'remove', 'history'],
            inline: { inDropdown: true },
            blockType: { inDropdown: true },
            fontSize: { inDropdown: true },
            fontFamily: { inDropdown: true },
            list: { inDropdown: true },
            textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
            colorPicker: { inDropdown: true },
            embedded: { inDropdown: true },
            remove: { inDropdown: true },
            history: { inDropdown: true },
         }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>     
    </>
  );
};

export default function Tabs({ data }) {
  return (
    <TabsComponent forceRenderTabPanel>
      <TabList>
        {data.map(({ name }, i) => (
          <Tab key={name}>Question {i + 1}</Tab>
        ))}
      </TabList>
      {data.map(({ name, typeProof }) => (
        <TabPanel key={name}>
          <TabContent {...{ name, typeProof }} />
        </TabPanel>
      ))}
    </TabsComponent>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's weird, I have no explanation for that but I've changed only in `index.js`:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

by :

```
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Is there an explanation ? I would be glad to understand that...

Comment: For react 17 you can't use createRoot , because it's a feature on React 18 , I am suspect that your React version wasn't React 18

Comment: I have React18, using createRoot works but if I use react-draft-wysiyg then it's not working, I have to change the index.js file.

Comment: Another hint for you [withCreateRoot](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-spothm) it works with createRoot render , difference is usage of StrictMode @Zokulko

Comment: But, here in your code you're not using createRoot, but StrictMode as I posted

Comment: I have use 
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) 
root.render(<App tab="home" />); without Strict mode , it means problem related with strict mode

Comment: Please check your link, [withCreateRoot](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-spothm?file=/src/index.js), in your index.js it's using StrictMode not CreateRoot

Comment: Try now , sorry forgot to save it  [withCreateRoot](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-1egpmc?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thanks I will leave as it is with StrictMode, that's what is advised on other forums!

Comment: I am having the same issue but when I use your solution (it works but) i get an error in the console: Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Are you seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your codes by this example [SandboxExample](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-poincare-v2rj5?file=/src/App.js)

I think your Sandbox dependency configuration is not good also I have found something like this , what I did , I have create a new Sandbox add dependencies **react-draft-wysiwyg** and **draft-js** , import Editor and use it in the App component like you used on your files , and everything is worked , try to clear your app , read this [npx Create React APP](https://create-react-app.dev/)

[image] [My Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-sea-cxxrqp?file=/src/App.js) this is my Sandbox example with **functional components**

Hope it will be **helpful** for you

Comment: Hi, is there an example using functions instead of class?

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpfull [Article](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-rich-text-editors-in-react-using-draft-js-and-react-draft-wysiwyg/)

Comment: I've already check it :)

Comment: Read my answer update and check sandbox example @Zokulko

Comment: That's weird I don't have this error, plus it's almost the same code that I have but still not working (I tried to insert it in my code), I don't know if I'm using an import that makes the use of wysiwyg disbable...

Comment: Enjoy [Your functional app with working dropdown](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-xys4jk?file=/src/Tabs.jsx)  @Zokulko

Comment: I have replace  "react": "^17.0.2", "react-dom": "^17.0.2", dependencies , also have changes on index.js , try to understand what is happening on react-tabs , but now you will be sure that you have wrong dependencies. Hope these all will be helpful for you @Zokulko

Comment: I think that createRoot is a new update for React 18, and maybe we need to remove all node modules and install again , or create a new sandbox

Comment: Well that's weird, the dependencies can remain the same, but the index.js has to change ( your index.js is the same as mine (the one that doesn't work). But now, since I changed it, it works but I don't know why is it working this way...

Comment: When I create my sandbox , I have use create-react-app , and as I know installed version is React 17 also for REACT-DOM , in 17 version we can use ReacDom.render method , and it work for me by this way , on your example I saw usage of React 18 version , also for ReactDOM , with createRoot method in the index.js, I don't sure that react 18 was installed on sandbox , read https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis , where is the warning that we need to use createRoot ? Have you this warning on the console ?

Comment: I mean have you got some deprication message ? @Zokulko

Comment: I am happy that your problem solved

Comment: No deprecation message, but thanks to your hint, I managed to solve it. Thanks man!

Comment: Have you already used Yup/Formik with react because I've opened a new issue [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078650/react-how-do-i-raise-a-warning-if-a-specific-input-field-is-empty-with-yup) and [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72080906/react-turn-my-code-using-formik-or-textfield-if-i-want-to-use-yup). They are slighlty the same, if you can give me some hints please!

Answer (score 0):

also note that react strict mode causes this "dropdown options not showing" error :

https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/1291#issuecomment-1203348769

Answer (score 0):

If you are using next js change `reactStrictMode: false` in  **next.config.js**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).