# REACT- Why using 'style' with react-draft-wysiwyg is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-draft-wysiwyg

Is there a way to delimit my textboxes in a rectangle and give a default height for them ?
I tried using `style` in my `<Editor />` but it's not working.

```
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

const TabContent = ({ name, typeProof }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(
  () => EditorState.createEmpty(),);    

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Editor
          editorState={text}
          onEditorStateChange={setText}
          wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
          editorClassName="editorClassName"
          toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
          placeholder="Enter your text here:"
          style={{
            height: 200,
            margin: 12,
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: "2px"
          }}
          toolbar={{
              options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'colorPicker', 'embedded', 'remove', 'history'],
         ...
         }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>     
    </>
  );
};
```

Here my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/Tabs.jsx:1108-1231)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to use

editorStyle={{
height: 200, margin: 12,borderWidth: 0.5,padding: 10,borderRadius: "2px"
}}

attribute instead of **style**

[image]

[image]

it works for me
`

Comment: Hi, yeah it works thanks man! I've another issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058578/react-dropdowns-are-not-working-using-react-draft-wysiwyg), the dropdowns are not working like  `block type`, `font`. If you have an idea ?

Comment: @HakonSargsyan, It would be great to add code or sandbox instead of code screenshots.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem of some items not working?

Comment: hmm , what do you mean @LayTexas

Comment: I want to know if you found the solution, because I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Which problem you mean ? style issue solved , I wrote solution on the answer @LayTexas