# What's wrong in my index.js file that raise me this error react-dom.development.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-devtools

when I check the console I get :

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot
```

I'm using `"react-dom": "^18.0.0"`, `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"`. But then when I use `createRoot` in my `index.js` I don't have the error but some functionnalities are not working (such as this issue that I get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058578/dropdowns-are-not-working-using-react-draft-wysiwyg-in-react-js))

What I have:

```
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

What I tried :

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementbyId("root")
root.render(<App/>);
```

you never imported reactDOM.

Comment: Hi, when I'm on my react page I get  this error :`index.js:63 Unexpected text node: . A text node cannot be a child of a <View>` And my index.js is the same as yours.

Comment: @Zokulko can you post your current index.js so I can take a look at it?

Comment: My index is this one : `import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);`
I have a warning that it's not longer supported in React18, and when I change by your solution I haven't the warning 'not supported...' but I have some functionnalities in my app that doesn't work... see here the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058578/dropdowns-are-not-working-using-react-draft-wysiwyg-in-react-js)

Comment: @Zokulko you should import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client" not from "react-dom"

Comment: when I do that then I got a blank page